# R code - split column each specific row values

Tags: r, split

I have the following data frame:

```
col1
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
1
2
```

And I would like to split the data every 1 value as:

data1 being

```
col1
1
2
3
```

data2 being

```
col1
1
2
3
4
```

and data3 being

```
col1
1
2
```

Do you have a way to do that?

Comment: Use `split`. For a data.frame named dat, `split(dat, cumsum(dat$col1 == 1))`. will return a named list of data.frames with the desired structure. Or `split(dat, paste0("data", cumsum(dat$col1 == 1)))` will provide the desired names.

Comment: Great ! Thank you. Perfect solution.